# Minimum Content Size of Window is not working

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

Every time I run my app it opens with no **width**. 
 I've setted the **minimum content size** for my window but it doesn't work. 
 If I try to make it wider with the arrows it goes immediately to the correct size. 
 I have a Split View Controller with two views, each of them with the half of the minimum width.
 [image]
How can I set the minimum size when I open the app?

Comment: Are you doing anything in code to overwrite the window size settings? Everything looks fine in your IB settings. Even if you create a new project, the default window works as expected so something else must be going on under the hood.

Comment: no in the code I don't change the size.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but this solved my problem. It's a strange way but it works:

```
class SplitViewController: NSSplitViewController {

    @IBOutlet var mySplitView: NSSplitView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.

        mySplitView.wantsLayer = true

    }

    override func splitView(splitView: NSSplitView, effectiveRect proposedEffectiveRect: NSRect, forDrawnRect drawnRect: NSRect, ofDividerAtIndex dividerIndex: Int) -> NSRect {
        return NSZeroRect
    }
}
```

**Update:**
For some reason it's not working. Still didn't solve the problem.